# Fix Arrow and Tickmark in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How to fix the arrow and tick marks (years) below to look good.In addition, how to add line from the bars to year number below as shown in the attached image.

Here is my outcome.

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,twoside,final,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % Arrows library
\usepackage[pdftex,a4paper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref} % with basic options
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}% Redefine the page margins 


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\textwidth/47] % Adjusted scale
        % Draw the horizontal line with an arrow at the end, extending beyond 2040
        \draw[thick, -{Triangle[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,0) -- (47,0); % Extend line beyond 2040
        
        % Draw tick marks and label for each year from 1994 to 2040
        \foreach \year in {1994,1995,...,2040} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{\year-1994}
            \draw (\xpos,0.25) -- (\xpos,-0.25) node[below] {\tiny \year};
        }
        
        
        % Additional gradient bar from 2016 to 2040
        \shade[left color=green, right color=red, middle color=yellow] (22,2.6) rectangle (46,3.0);
        % Add text inside the additional colored bar
        \node[text=black] at (36,2.8) {20neo};
        % Red dashed arrow starting at the end of the "A330-900" gradient bar
        \draw[dashed, ->, >=latex, line width=0.2cm, draw=red] (46.2,2.8) -- (47.2,2.8);
        
        
        % Gradient bar from 2020 to 2040
        \shade[left color=green, right color=red, middle color=yellow] (26,2) rectangle (46,2.4);
        % Add text inside the additional colored bar
        \node[text=black] at (36,2.2) {800};
        % Red dashed arrow starting at the end of the "A330-800" gradient bar
        \draw[dashed, ->, >=latex, line width=0.2cm, draw=red] (46.2,2.2) -- (47.2,2.2);
        
        
        % Gradient bar from 2018 to 2040
        \shade[left color=green, right color=red, middle color=yellow] (24,1.4) rectangle (46,1.8);
        % Add text inside the new colored bar
        \node[text=black] at (35,1.6) {900};
        % Red dashed arrow starting at the end of the "A330-900" gradient bar
        \draw[dashed, ->, >=latex, line width=0.2cm, draw=red] (46.2,1.6) -- (47.2,1.6);
        
        
        % Draw colored bar (red) from 1998 to 2019 for A330-200
        \fill[red] (4,0.8) rectangle (25,1.2);
        % Add text inside the red colored bar
        \node[text=white] at (14.5,1.0) {200};
        % Draw a dashed line at the level and height of the red colored bar from 2019 to 2039
        \draw[dashed, red, line width=0.4cm] (25,1.0) -- (45,1.0); % Line from 2019 to 2039
        
        
        % Draw a blue colored bar from 1994 to 2020 above the horizontal line
        \fill[blue] (0,0.3) rectangle (26,0.7);
        % Add text inside the blue colored bar
        \node[text=white] at (13,0.5) {300};
        % Draw a dashed blue line from 2020 to 2040 at the level and height of the first colored bar
        \draw[dashed, blue, line width=0.4cm] (26,0.5) -- (46,0.5); % Line up to 2040
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you want to draw more than one diagram I suggest an approach that uses a few keys to remove many of the hard-coded values and calculations.

The `year` function can be used to subtract the value 2000 of the year numbers. The PGFMath function evaluates the shortening amount of the end tip specification to change where the shaded rectangle ends.

Both loops that places the bars are one one path so that the `marker` can be drawn in the background.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{arrowlengthend}{0}{%
  \begingroup\nullfont
    \pgf@arrow@compute@shortening\pgf@end@tip@sequence
    \pgfmath@returnone\pgf@xa\endgroup}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  outer sep=auto,
  reset row counter/.code=\setcounter{tikzrowcounter}{0},
  increment row/.code=\stepcounter{tikzrowcounter}%
                      \tikzset{shift=(up:\value{tikzrowcounter})},
  edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}},
  rect to/.style={to path=rectangle(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}
\newcounter{tikzrowcounter}
\tikzset{
  bar height/.initial=4mm,         % controls the height of the bars
  bar/.style={line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar height}},
  bar arrow rect/.style={
    draw=none, left color=green, right color=red, middle color=yellow, rect to},
  bar arrow style/.style={
    nodes=black, bar, -{Latex[red, length=+0pt +2, width=+0pt +1.4]}},
  bar dashy/.style={dashed, dash phase=3pt},
  bar marker style/.style={arrows=-{Latex[round]}, thick, purple, line to},
  %
  bar with dash/.style args={#1-#2-#3:#4}{
    edges=bar, nodes=white,
    insert path={
      (year #1, 0) edge[line to]   node{#4} (year #2, 0)
      (year #2, 0) edge[line to, bar dashy] (year #3, 0)
      [bar marker={#1}]}},
  bar with tip/.style args={#1-#2:#3}{
    bar arrow style, nodes=black,
    insert path={
      (year #1,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar height}/2) edge[bar arrow rect] node{#3}
      ([xshift=-arrowlengthend]year #2, \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar height}/2)
      (year #1,0) edge[line to, tips, path only] (year #2, 0)
      [bar marker={#1}]}},
  bar marker/.style={
    insert path={
      node[purple!50!black, rotate=90, above, scale=.6] at (year #1, 0) {#1}
      [behind path](year #1, -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar height}/2) coordinate(@)
                    edge[bar marker style={#1}] (@|-start)}},
  %
  bar diagram/.style={
    y=6mm,             % controls the distance between rows
    declare function={year(\y)=\y-2000;},
    reset row counter}} % if you have more than one diagram
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\textwidth/47, bar diagram]
\draw[thick, -{Triangle[length=3mm, width=2mm]}, shorten <=+-1mm, shorten >=+-4mm]
     (year 1994,0) coordinate (start) -- (year 2040,0);
\draw[thin, xstep=1, ystep=0] (year 1994, -1.00mm) grid (year 2040, 1.00mm);
\draw[thin, xstep=5, ystep=0] (year 1994, -2.00mm) grid (year 2040, 2.00mm);
\foreach \y in {1995, 2000, ..., 2040}
  \node[below] at (year \y, -2.5mm) {\y};

\path % one path allows us to easily place the marker in the background
      % see “behind path” in style “marker”
  foreach \c/\t in {blue/1994-2020-2040:300, red/1998-2019-2039:200}{
    [increment row, edges=\c, bar with dash/.expand once=\t]
  }
  foreach \t in {2018-2040:900, 2020-2040:800, 2016-2040:20neo}{
    [increment row, bar with tip/.expand once=\t]
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

- to fix the arrow, with `shorten >=-4pt`
- tick marks (years) below to look good, I suggest indicating every 5 years
- add line from the bars to year number, with `\draw`
- To improve readability, you can define styles in tikzset
- You can also use loops
- I didn't simplify the last bars...

  ```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % Arrows library

   \begin{document}
   \tikzset{
       myarrow/.style = {thick,-{Triangle[length=3mm, width=2mm]},shorten <=-2pt-\pgflinewidth,},
       myshade/.style = {left color=green, right color=red, middle color=yellow},
       mytext/.style = {black},
       myBigarrow/.style = {->, >=latex, shorten >=-4pt,line width=0.2cm, draw=red},
       mymark/.style = {blue},
       }
   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\textwidth/47] % Adjusted scale
       % Draw the horizontal line with an arrow at the end, extending beyond 2040
       \draw[myarrow] (0,0) -- (47.5,0); %<-- change in 47.5  Extend line beyond 2040

       % Draw tick marks and label for each year from 1994 to 2040
       \foreach \year in {1994,1995,...,2040} {
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{\year-1994}
           \draw (\xpos,0.15) -- (\xpos,-0.15);
       }
       \foreach \year in {1995,2000,...,2040} {
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{\year-1994}
           \draw [thick](\xpos,0.25) -- (\xpos,-0.25) node[below] {\tiny \year};
       }

       % Additional gradient bar from 2016 to 2040
       \foreach \x/\y/\lib in {22/2.6/20neo,24/1.4/800,26/2/900}%
           {
               \shade[myshade] (\x,\y) rectangle (45.4,\y+0.4) node[midway]{\lib};
               \draw[myBigarrow] (46.2,\y+0.2) -- +(1,0);        
               \draw [mymark](\x,\y) -- (\x,0);
               }

       % Draw colored bar (red) from 1998 to 2019 for A330-200
       \fill[red] (4,0.8) rectangle (25,1.2);
       % Add text inside the red colored bar
       \node[text=white] at (14.5,1.0) {200};
       % Draw a dashed line at the level and height of the red colored bar from 2019 to 2039
       \draw[dashed, red, line width=0.4cm] (25,1.0) -- (45,1.0); % Line from 2019 to 2039


       % Draw a blue colored bar from 1994 to 2020 above the horizontal line
       \fill[blue] (0,0.3) rectangle (26,0.7);
       % Add text inside the blue colored bar
       \node[text=white] at (13,0.5) {300};
       % Draw a dashed blue line from 2020 to 2040 at the level and height of the first colored bar
       \draw[dashed, blue, line width=0.4cm] (26,0.5) -- (46,0.5); % Line up to 2040
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do it. Some remarks:

1. I think you shouldn't forget to include `transform shape`.
2. I did some refactoring of `grad`, and added a new style `ln`, where you can vary the appearance of the vertical lines. Draw them last, if they shall overwrite the other bars.
3. I made a suggestion on rotated year numbers.
4. The shaded bars look a bit strange: there's probably a better way to do it. For now I just reduced the rectangle size by 0.4cm, so it stops before the tip begins. I suggest to refactor the tip-related options as well.
5. To reference the left sides of the bars I remember their coordinates like  `\shade[grad] (22,2.6) coordinate (S1) ..`. and use them later.
6. Finally, draw all those verticals like `\draw[ln] (S1) -- +(0,-2.6);`, which you could shorten into a `\foreach` loop, which takes value pais like (indicative) `S1*-2.6`

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,twoside,final,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % Arrows library
\usepackage[pdftex,a4paper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref} % with basic options
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}% Redefine the page margins 


\begin{document}
    % <<< don't forget transform shape ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\textwidth/47,transform shape, % Adjusted scale
        % <<< some refactoring ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        grad/.style={left color=green, right color=red, middle color=yellow},
        % <<< new ~~~~~~~~~~~~
        ln/.style={dashed,line width=3pt,teal},
    ]
        % Draw the horizontal line with an arrow at the end, extending beyond 2040
        \draw[thick, -{Triangle[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,0) -- (47,0); % Extend line beyond 2040
        
        % Draw tick marks and label for each year from 1994 to 2040
        \foreach \year in {1994,1995,...,2040} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{\year-1994}
            % <<< suggestion ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \draw (\xpos,0.25) -- (\xpos,-0.25) 
                                    node[anchor=east,rotate=90] {\tiny \year};
        }
        
        
        % Additional gradient bar from 2016 to 2040
        % <<< remember left coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \shade[grad] (22,2.6) coordinate (S1) rectangle (45.6,3.0);%<<< suggestion
        % Add text inside the additional colored bar
        \node[text=black] at (36,2.8) {20neo};
        % Red dashed arrow starting at the end of the "A330-900" gradient bar
       \draw[dashed, ->, >=latex, line width=0.2cm, draw=red] (46.2,2.8) -- (47.2,2.8);
        
        
        % Gradient bar from 2020 to 2040
        \shade[grad] (26,2) coordinate (S2) rectangle (46,2.4);
        % Add text inside the additional colored bar
        \node[text=black] at (36,2.2) {800};
        % Red dashed arrow starting at the end of the "A330-800" gradient bar
        \draw[dashed, ->, >=latex, line width=0.2cm, draw=red] (46.2,2.2) -- (47.2,2.2);
        
        
        % Gradient bar from 2018 to 2040
        \shade[grad] (24,1.4) coordinate (S3) rectangle (46,1.8);
        % Add text inside the new colored bar
        \node[text=black] at (35,1.6) {900};
        % Red dashed arrow starting at the end of the "A330-900" gradient bar
        \draw[dashed, ->, >=latex, line width=0.2cm, draw=red] (46.2,1.6) -- (47.2,1.6);
        
        
        % Draw colored bar (red) from 1998 to 2019 for A330-200
        \fill[red] (4,0.8) coordinate (B1) rectangle (25,1.2);
        % Add text inside the red colored bar
        \node[text=white] at (14.5,1.0) {200};
        % Draw a dashed line at the level and height of the red colored bar from 2019 to 2039
        \draw[dashed, red, line width=0.4cm] (25,1.0) -- (45,1.0); % Line from 2019 to 2039
        
        
        % Draw a blue colored bar from 1994 to 2020 above the horizontal line
        \fill[blue] (0,0.3) coordinate (B2) rectangle (26,0.7);
        % Add text inside the blue colored bar
        \node[text=white] at (13,0.5) {300};
        % Draw a dashed blue line from 2020 to 2040 at the level and height of the first colored bar
        \draw[dashed, blue, line width=0.4cm] (26,0.5) -- (46,0.5); % Line up to 2040

        % <<< lines; you could replace it by a foreach on value-pairs ~~~~
        \draw[ln] (S1) -- +(0,-2.6);
        \draw[ln] (S2) -- +(0,-2.0);
        \draw[ln] (S3) -- +(0,-1.4);
        \draw[ln] (B1) -- +(0,-0.8);
        \draw[ln] (B2) -- +(0,-0.3);
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```